# how can we create windows phone 8 App in 32bit system

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am new Windows Phone Application developer.
Is it possible to create windows phone 8 App in 32bit system?
if no. then how can we create windows app for WP8?

Answer (score 0):

A 64-bit OS is required to install the Windows Phone SDK 8.0 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471).

If you can't upgrade your system, you can still install the [Windows Phone SDK 7.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471) and start developping applications (WP7 apps work on WP8 devices).

Comment: thanx @ Olivier Payen

Answer (score 0):

When you download the Windows phone 8 SDK ([here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471)) You can read, in the "requirements part" this :

```
Operating system type:
    Windows 8 64-bit (x64) client versions

Hardware:
    6.5 GB of free hard disk space
    4 GB RAM
    64-bit (x64) CPU
```

You wont install the Windows Phone SDK (for windows phone 8) in a Computer With not a 64bit... and with Not Windows 8 (Windows 7 64bits don't work too... I switch to Windows 8 for that...)

Also, Windows Phone 7 applications Works on the Windows Phone 8 devices... And, you can install a [Windows phone 7 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=27570) in a 32bits Computer with Windows Vista or Later OS..

So, You don't have a solution for create a Windows Phone 8 application if you don't have a Windows 8 OS and a 64 bits computer.

But, It's new, maybe you can use "[Windows Phone App Studio](http://apps.windowsstore.com/default.htm)" if your application is not too complicated...